CSS to produce hierarchical ordered list that results in 1, 1.1, a, i
Using the helpful answer by Jakub Jirutka in answer to a similar question, I can produce a very nicely aligned hierarchical ordered list as follows (see screenshot):

Level 1

1.1 Level 2
1.1.1 Level 3
1.1.1.1 Level 4
Example
But I want to convert "Level 3" to lower-alpha  and "Level 4" to lower-roman (ideally, if possible, the lower-alpha and lower-roman would be enclosed by round brackets - (a), (i) etc.. )
Is this possible?


ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
}

li li {
  margin: 0;
}

li li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  padding-top: 0.6em;
}

body {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
}
<ol>
  <li>Intellectual property
    <ol>
      <li>Except to the extent permitted under this Agreement, as either may be amended from time to time by mutual agreement of the Parties:
        <ol>
          <li>
            each Party shall not (and shall not permit or procure a third party, either directly or indirectly to):
            <ol>
              <li>
                use any Intellectual Property of the other Party (or any of its Affiliates) without the prior written approval of the other Party (or any of its Affiliates);
              </li>
              <li>
                disassemble, decompile or reverse engineer the whole or any part of the other Party's Intellectual Property;
              </li>
              <li>
                obtain or attempt to obtain the algorithms for the other Party's Intellectual Property;
              </li>
              <li>
                at any time do or cause to be done, any act or things contesting or in any way impairing the other Party's Intellectual Property;
              </li>
              <li>
                use, apply for registration of, or otherwise promote any trade mark, name, logo or other word or mark that is the same as, or deceptively similar to, or substantially identical with, a trade mark, name, logo, word or mark of the other Party; and
              </li>
              <li>
                advertise or otherwise promote the other Party in conjunction with the first Party's name in such a way that would imply or tend to imply that the first Party has a proprietary interest in the other Party's Intellectual Property.
              </li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li>each Party shall:
            <ol>
              <li>
                ensure that all trademarks, copyrights and restricted rights notices that relate to the other Parties' Intellectual Property are reproduced in all activities;
              </li>
              <li>
                immediately notify the other Parties in writing of any actual, suspended, threatened or anticipated infringement of the other Party's Intellectual Property that comes to the first Party's attention; and
              </li>
              <li>
                in its absolute discretion, choose to prosecute any infringement of its Intellectual Property.
              </li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>


        <li> None of the Parties will assign or purport to assign any of the other Party's Intellectual Property.</li>

        <li>Each Party warrants that its Intellectual Property does not infringe the intellectual property rights of a third party.</li>
    </ol>



I assume one way is to create <ol type="a"> and <ol type="i"> tags in the HTML and create CSS rules targeting that (although I can't figure that out either)?

Try this answer use list-style-type.

You can target level 3 and 4 specifically.
According to counter docs, you can specify as second argument the counter display.
Combining those, here's the solution:


body {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 85%;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
  width: 20px;

}

li li {
  margin: 0;
}

li li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  padding-top: 0.6em;
}

ol>li>ol>li>ol li:before {
  content: counter(item, lower-latin) ") ";
}

ol>li>ol>li>ol>li>ol li:before {
  content: counter(item, lower-roman) ") ";
}
<ol>
  <li>Intellectual property
    <ol>
      <li>Except to the extent permitted under this Agreement, as either may be amended from time to time by mutual agreement of the Parties:
        <ol>
          <li>
            each Party shall not (and shall not permit or procure a third party, either directly or indirectly to):
            <ol>
              <li>
                use any Intellectual Property of the other Party (or any of its Affiliates) without the prior written approval of the other Party (or any of its Affiliates);
              </li>
              <li>
                disassemble, decompile or reverse engineer the whole or any part of the other Party's Intellectual Property;
              </li>
              <li>
                obtain or attempt to obtain the algorithms for the other Party's Intellectual Property;
              </li>
              <li>
                at any time do or cause to be done, any act or things contesting or in any way impairing the other Party's Intellectual Property;
              </li>
              <li>
                use, apply for registration of, or otherwise promote any trade mark, name, logo or other word or mark that is the same as, or deceptively similar to, or substantially identical with, a trade mark, name, logo, word or mark of the other Party; and
              </li>
              <li>
                advertise or otherwise promote the other Party in conjunction with the first Party's name in such a way that would imply or tend to imply that the first Party has a proprietary interest in the other Party's Intellectual Property.
              </li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li>each Party shall:
            <ol>
              <li>
                ensure that all trademarks, copyrights and restricted rights notices that relate to the other Parties' Intellectual Property are reproduced in all activities;
              </li>
              <li>
                immediately notify the other Parties in writing of any actual, suspended, threatened or anticipated infringement of the other Party's Intellectual Property that comes to the first Party's attention; and
              </li>
              <li>
                in its absolute discretion, choose to prosecute any infringement of its Intellectual Property.
              </li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>


        <li> None of the Parties will assign or purport to assign any of the other Party's Intellectual Property.</li>

        <li>Each Party warrants that its Intellectual Property does not infringe the intellectual property rights of a third party.</li>
    </ol>



You may also try instead of the . another symbol )
ol>li>ol>li>ol li:before {
  content: counter(item, lower-latin) ") ";
}

ol>li>ol>li>ol>li>ol li:before {
  content: counter(item, lower-roman) ") ";
}


Thanks! The alignment however is slightly off, which doesn't happen for some reason in the original.
Compare the original Ip-clause-orig.png against IP-clause-2.png

You can define a fixed width for all li::before. Answer updated

Thanks to @IT Goldman I think I have solved the question. IT Goldman's answer allows you to change the Levels 3 and 4 to lower-alpha and lower-roman respectively. But the alignment of the content of the list was off (see my comment to @IT Goldman's solution). The solution below appears to fix the alignment problem (any improvements or things I have missed welcomed)
body {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 85%;
}

ol {
  display: table;
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}

li {
  display: table-row;
  counter-increment: item;
  
  
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
  padding-top: 0.6em;
  padding-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 0.6em;
  
}

li li:after {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

li li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}

ol>li>ol>li>ol li:before {
  content: counter(item, lower-latin) ") ";
}

ol>li>ol>li>ol>li>ol li:before {
  content: counter(item, lower-roman) ". ";
}

